# When solving PDEs by separation of variables, why are we allowed to divide by the dependent variable?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

When solving PDEs in physics, one common tool in use is separation of variables. However, to me, there exists a big problem when one divides both sides of a equation by some function that might be $0$.

Here in [this link](http://users.aber.ac.uk/ruw/teach/260/laplace.php) (*Laplace's equation 1: Separation of variables*, Rudolf Winter, 2008), when we divided by $XY$, should not we assume $XY$ is not $0$? But it seems like $XY$ could be 0 in the general solution. Why is that?

Comment: Once you find a solution "by hook or by crook" you can then plug in your solution to confirm that it really is valid.

Comment: [Related and recent](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2445816/8157)

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1734715/648911).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the separation of variables in $D\backslash U$, where $D$ is the whole domain and $U=\{(x,y)|XY=0\}$. The interior of $U$, denoted by $$\mathring{U}=\{(x,y)\in U| \text{There exists a neighborhood } W \text{ s.t. } (x,y)\in W\subset U\}$$
is empty. Then we can extend the solution to the whole domain by continuity.

Lapalace's equation as an example:

1)  If $X=0, Y\neq 0$, then $Y\frac{{\rm d}^2X}{{\rm d}x^2}+X\frac{{\rm d}^2Y}{{\rm d}y^2}=0$ implies $\frac{{\rm d}^2X}{{\rm d}x^2}=0$, hence the equation
$$
\frac{{\rm d}^2X}{{\rm d}x^2}+k^2X=0
$$ 
still holds.
Similarly for $X\neq0,Y=0$.

2) If $X=Y=0$, I denote $U=\{(x,y)|X(x,y)=Y(x,y)=0\}$, The interior of $U$ is empty(if not , then it is a zero constant solution in an open subset, hence the whole domain $D$). Now you can solve the problem safely in $D\backslash U$ and then extend to the whole domain by continuity.

More general $W=\{(x,y)|XY=0\}$ is a set whose interior is empty, hence we can always safely solve the question in $D\backslash U$ that $XY\neq 0$, then extend to the whole set by continuity. Maybe these thoughts can be modified to explain the validity of separation of variables.